# Relationship of confidence interval of parameter estimated and regression bounds

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, matlab

I am using Matlab and have fitted a line of the form `y=ax+b` using the curve fitting tool box. In the output I get the estimates for `a` and `b` along with their 95%confidence intervals. Then, I can also generate 95% confidence bounds of the regression line (indicated in dotted blue of the below figure). So what does this confidence bound mean? Is it generated from the confidence intervals of the estimates?
[image]

Comment: This does not look like a confidence band for the line.  It seems closer to prediction bands for individual values.  Could you explain how you computed these lines?

Comment: @whuber So, does the confidence band for the line gets based on the confidence interval of the estimated parameters? I was trying to get the 99% confidence interval of the estimates and in the curve fitting tool box I found this option as `prediction bounds`. I should look into what it really means.

Comment: The confidence band for the line is determined by a *joint* confidence region for the parameters.  Prediction bounds are much wider because they have to account for uncertainty in each individual response.